# Using JS Event Listener to Determine Which PHP File to Display

Tags: javascript, php, security, bootstrap-5

I'm using two different PHP files:

```
tabs.php
accordion.php
```

Which are running a loop through the same data but displaying the data differently.

Whichever file gets displayed depends on the users screen size.

To determine this, I'm using a function with an event listener.

```
function switchOver(screenSize) {
    if (screenSize.matches) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = `<?php include 'accordion.php';?>`;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = `<?php include 'tabs.php';?>`;
    }
}
var screenSize = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
switchOver(screenSize)
screenSize.addListener(switchOver)
```

Once the JS has determined the screen size, it just spits the php out into a container div

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

On desktop the content will appear as Bootstrap 5 tabs and on mobile they will display as accordions. I know this isn't truly responsive but it is working as expected.

I have a few questions that hopefully someone with more technical knowledge can clear up for me:

1. Is this secure?
2. Is there a more graceful alternative I could learn about?

Any advice is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're just using PHP and BS ... not some other server side JS based rendering engine.  If so then I'm a bit confused about the mixture of both server-side (PHP) and client-side (JS) rendering.  In your example the `<?php include(...` just injects the rendered source of the PHP into the html.  *(Right click and "view source" on the output and you'll see the resulting output is embedded into the JS.  Any non-JS rendering will break the output on the browser.  e.g. a single quote "`" will close the string and you'll get JS errors on the browser render.)*  Not the best way to do this.

Now to your questions:

1. "Is this secure?"  Not sure what the question is .. it's as secure as PHP can be:  Maybe search *"how secure is PHP"*, AND how secure JS is ...
2. "a more graceful alternative"?  That's the amazing thing about coding .. if you put 30 developers in a room and ask for a block of code you'll get 30 different answers --- each giving you the output you want.  Tom Scott has a brilliant YouTube video on [FizzBuzz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPZ0pIK_wsc).

Given the parameters of your question - this is how I would have done it:

a. You are already rendering the entire content of the two PHP files...

b. ... so there is no bandwidth benefits, ...

c. ... so the JS is superfluous and just adds complexity.

d. As this is a Bootstrap question then you can render the output, with no JS like so:

```html
  <div id="test">
    <div class="d-block d-sm-none"><?php include 'accordion.php';?></div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block"><?php include 'tabs.php';?></div>
  </div>
```

This uses the simple Display Properties that BS5 offers - see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: Thanks for laying this out for me, I can see now how I've taken a much longer route than I actually needed to!

I'll read up some more and check out Tom Scott's video. I think my logic is lacking when it comes to development as I've spent most of my career as a designer so everything for me is visual. Thanks for your help Vino.